# Define Derivatives of Functions

Tags: functions

I would like to replace the derivative of a function by my own definition. For example I have the function `a`:

```
a[x_]:=Sin[x];
```

And I would like to assign now:

```
a'[x_]:=-Sin[x];
```

This gives me an error.
What works for me is defining:

```
a[x_?NumberQ]:=Sin[x];
```

and then applying the above definition of `a'`.
But this solution seems not right to me, since i would change the way *Mathematica* treats the both definitions of the function `a`.

- Can someone explain why exactly the second solution works. What is inherently different between the two definitions?
- How is the assignment of the derivative done properly when defining `a` without the `?NumberQ`?

Comment: You have to `Unprotect` `D`/`Derivative` in order to overwrite pattern matching rules for built-in functions. That's because `a'[x]` actually evaluates to `Derivative[1][a][x]` which means it belongs to `Derivative`.

Comment: Are you sure that what you are trying to do makes sense? The derivative of Sin[x] is *not* -Sin[x] and to try and define it this way would appear to be nonsense. You can define some other operator "myDerivative" that has this property, but it is not the (regular) derivative.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Then: `Unprotect[Derivative];
a[x_] := Sin[x];
Derivative[1][a][x_] := -Sin[x];` should work? It somehow does not for me.

Comment: @bills Its a dummy example to understand the concept. It make sense to provide the derivative of a function in order to not calculate the derivative each time when it is called. Also using approximate versions of derivatives which are algebraically simpler could be an application.

Comment: You can avoid calculating the derivative each time it appears by defining using Set instead of SetDelayed. Unprotecting and redefining built-in functions (like Derivative) will lead you to grief sooner or later.

Comment: Thats not true at least if I havent misunderstood you. It is indeed faster to define the derivative. Have a look at this example: 
`int = Interpolation[{1, 2, 4, 8, 9}];
a[x_] = int[x];
b[x_?NumberQ] := int[x];
b'[x_?NumberQ] = int'[x];
AbsoluteTiming[Null[Table[b'[i], {i, 1, 5, .01}, {j, 0, 5, 0.01}]];]
AbsoluteTiming[Null[Table[a'[i], {i, 1, 5, .01}, {j, 0, 5, 0.01}]];]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) is not a protected symbol just so you can define derivatives for functions as you desire (although, I think it's a good idea to use [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for `a` anyways). The problem is that you are trying to define (sub)[`SubValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues) of [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative), and you are running into a premature evaluation. In particular:

```
Clear[a]
a[x_] := Sin[x]
a'
a'[Pi]
```

> Cos[#1] &
>
> -1

Notice how `a'` already evaluates to `Cos[#1]&`. So, when you try to define:

```
a'[x_] := -Sin[x]
```

you are really trying to define:

```
(Cos[#1]&)[x_] := -Sin[x]
```

which is a definition for [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function), a protected symbol. If you had instead done:

```
a /: a' = -Sin[#]&
```

> -Sin[#1] &

then you would get the behavior you want:

```
a'[Pi]
```

> 0

Finally, your second definition of a doesn't run into this issue:

```
Clear[a]
a[x_?NumberQ] := Sin[x]
a'
```

> Derivative[1][a]

Notice how `Derivative[1][a]` now doesn't have a definition. Mathematica only creates such definitions when the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for `a` is not restricted.

Answer (score 4):

I find it a *really* bad idea to re-define how `D` calculates derivatives; I'm pretty sure that in the majority of use-cases I have encountered, it has never been a good idea to 'overload' `D` in such a manner and I am stating this as a matter of personal fact.

It can conceivably be considered as an appropriate approach to pursue by really experienced users that know what they are doing but I definitely do not consider myself to be among their rank so I don't use it.

Having said that, a way around the issue of `Unprotect`-ing built-in symbols in general and `D` in particular might be defining a '*wrapper*' function around the original built-in symbol.

Consider evaluating the following lines

```
 ClearAll[d]

 SetAttributes[d, HoldFirst]

 d[f_[x_]] := D[f[x], x]
```

We're using `HoldFirst` as a `Attribute` for our *derivative* operator `d` in order to *not* allow it to evaluate its input; this will come in handy later.

Symbol `d` now can be used to calculate *simple* first degree derivatives eg evaluating

```
f[x_]:=x^2

d[f[x]]
```

will return

```
2x
```

as expected.

Now, in order to address the theme of 'changing the derivative of a function', consider again the example of `f[x_]:=x^2` above but let's set its derivative equal to `3 x + 1`.

In order to accomplish this, we can evaluate the following

```
d[f[x_]] ^:= 3x+1
```

Note we are using `UpSetDelayed` (see [UpSetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html)).

Also note that, had we not used `HoldFirst` earlier in the attribute list of symbol `d`, we would not have been be able to use `UpSetDelayed` successfully; there would also be other unwanted side effects, such as the possibility that the definition of `d` might not have been able to identify its input correctly and would thus return unevaluated.

As an educational aside, we can clear all definitions made so far and attempt to evaluate everything again, with the *exception* of not using `HoldFirst`, this time. Doing that will produce two errors.

1. evaluating `d[f[x]]` will return un-evaluated ie `d[x^2]`
2. attempting to define our derivative operator will return an `UpSetDelayed::write` error message.

Issue no. 1 occurs because *Mathematica* evaluates `f[x]` before applying any rules to it. Evaluating `f[x]` produces `x^2` and our new operator `d` does not match any rule of the form `d[Power[x, 2]]` hence it returns un-evaluated.

Issue no. 2 occurs because `Power` is a built-in symbol and it is `Protected` thus not allowing us to modify rules associated with it (that is partly the issue we are trying to avoid with defining the wrapper function `d` for `D` in the first place).

Returning from this brief detour, after clearing all definitions once more, and evaluating everything, including `SetAttributes[f,HoldFirst]`, doing something like

```
 d[f[x]]
```

would return

```
 1+3x
```

as expected.

---

I include the notebook code as one unified piece for ease of replication

**Code block 1**

```
ClearAll[f, d]

SetAttributes[d, HoldFirst]

d[f_[x_]] := D[f[x], x]

f[x_] := x^2

d[f[x]]

d[f[x_]] ^:= 3 x + 1

d[f[x]]
```

**Code block 2** (to replicate errors)

```
ClearAll[f, d]

d[f_[x_]] := D[f[x], x]

f[x_] := x^2

d[f[x]]

d[f[x_]] ^:= 3 x + 1

d[f[x]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the OPs code from the comments, and without re-defining any built-in symbols, we can define the desired derivatives directly by giving them another name.

```
int = Interpolation[Range[100]^(1/2)];
ader[x_]  = D[int[x], x];
bder[x_] := D[int[x], x]; 
{AbsoluteTiming[Null[Table[ader[i], {i, 1, 5, .01}, {j, 0, 5, 0.01}]];], 
 AbsoluteTiming[Null[Table[bder[i], {i, 1, 5, .01}, {j, 0, 5, 0.01}]];]}

{{2.96934, Null},{4.21217, Null}}
```

So the first method, which takes the derivative only once, is faster. Here I have just defined the desired derivative functions with the names ader and bder instead of messing with the definitions of built-in functions.